# What happens to the Wiki of TFS 2018 when migrating to Azure DevOps Server 2019

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, migration, wiki

We are evaluating the migration from TFS 2018 to Azure DevOps 2019 Server.
Unfortunately we don't understand what happen to the Wiki pages.

In fact looks like that Azure DevOps 2019 uses Git based wikis while TFS 2018 was using a different approach.

Are going to loose all articles or they will be migrated?
We have both HTML and Markdown wiki articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS and Azure DevOps know two types of wiki. The **project wiki** and the **code wiki**. They can live happily side by side. Both are actually backed by Git, but the project wikis hide that fact quite nicely.

Comment: Small clarification. The `Project Wiki` is termed `Provisioned Wiki`. See [Provisioned wikis vs. published code as a wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/provisioned-vs-published-wiki?view=azure-devops)